# Transfer Videos From iOS5 Device to Computer Wirelessly: Possible?

Tags: ios

It seems that the majority of my device's content can now sync wirelesslly to my computer either via wifi sync or iCloud photostream.  Notably, photostream does not encompass videos.

**Is there a way to transfer videos from your iOS5 camera roll to your computer wirelessly, or does this still require a hard line, cable transfer?***

*I tried to get around this using Dropbox sync over wifi, but the 4S's HD videos were too large for the Dropbox app to handle.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it with videos, but I've had some decent results using [PhotoSync](http://www.photosync-app.com/). I think it's $2 or $3 on the app store, with a free Mac side client. Transfers photos and videos to/from your iOS library wirelessly without using iTunes. It also supports albums in iOS 5.

Comment: This response actually reminded me of another app I already have called CameraSync (http://bit.ly/rTaYK9), which sounds pretty similar to the one you recommended.  I have set it to upload new videos to dropbox (leaving photos unchecked and for photostream to deal with) - testing it now.  I will report back.  Thanks!

Comment: It was able to handle pre-4S videos, but crapped out on HD videos taken with the 4S, so CameraSync, at least, doesn't work.  Have you had any luck using PhotoSync to transfer HD videos taken with the 4S?  If so, I'll pick it up and give it a try.  Thanks.

Comment: No, I haven't got a 4S to test that out with, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The Eye-fi app does this, but it requires you have an Eye-fi account, which requires you purchase an eye-fi card.  They can be had relatively inexpensively now.

An advantage with eye-fi device, though, is that all your pictures *and* videos will end up on your computer, whether taken with your camera or iOS device(s), automatically.  It's a decent solution for getting everything from several camera sources into one spot.

The app is free, but you have to purchase the eye-fi device to get the account that will enable your iOS device to transfer its own photos and video automatically.  Shopping around, you'll probably find one for around $50.

Comment: I purchased an eye-fi card a while back but could not get the software to work with my Windows Vista machine.  Numerous contacts with their customer support were not all that helpful - they advised completely removing anti-virus software because their desktop application "behaved like a virus" which could cause problems with Windows.  I ultimately returned the card.  Great idea, poor execution (at least as of that time).

Comment: @Donnniegoat Ouch!  I recently got a card and it works flawlessly with my macbook pro.  I haven't tried using it with my windows machines yet.